# Creating standalone butter filter with Matlab coder

Tags: c++, matlab, function, compilation, matlab-coder

i'm trying to compile with Matlab Coder a custom function which includes a butterworth filter.
I've extracted the lines that give me problem with the Matlab coder function.

```
function [output] = myfilter(input,fs) %#codegen
f1 = 5;         % cuttoff low frequency to get rid of baseline wander
Wn = f1.*2./fs;   % cutt off based on fs
N  = 3;         % order of 3 less processing
[a,b] = butter(N,Wn); % bandpass filtering
output = filtfilt(a,b,input); % filtering
output = output/max(abs(output));
```

I'm getting an error when I launch the command to compile it:

`codegen -config:lib -launchreport myfilter -args {zeros(1,100),10}`

The output error is: **All inputs must be constant.**
I tried to use the function coder.const modifying the code as follows, but still have the same problem:

```
function [output] = myfilter(input,fs) %#codegen
f1 = 5;         % cuttoff low frequency to get rid of baseline wander
Wn = f1.*2./fs;   % cutt off based on fs
N  = 3;         % order of 3 less processing
[a,b] = coder.const(@butter,N,Wn); % bandpass filtering
a = coder.const(a);
b = coder.const(b);
output = filtfilt(a,b,input); % filtering
output = output/max(abs(output));
```

Can somebody help me with this issue? I'm new to Matlab Coder. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The function `butter` needs to have constant inputs. This means that when generating code MATLAB Coder must be able to determine values for all of them.

In this case, the code passes `Wn` which is computed from the top input `fs`. Because it depends on a top level input, `Wn` is not a constant.

Two options to consider:

1. Pass a literal constant for `Wn` in the call to `butter` like you did for `N`
2. Pass a constant to the codegen call for `fs` so that the computation for `Wn` can be constant folded

   ```
    codegen -config:lib -launchreport myfilter -args {zeros(1,100),coder.Constant(10)}
   ```

Comment: I tried option number 2 and It did work thanks! Another question...if I compile it in a MEX file and I want to supply a different value for **fs** how can I do?

Comment: You'll need to regenerate the MEX function with the new value. If you're familiar with C think of the constant like a `#define `. When you change the value you have to recompile.